# No type definitions in pre-defined IDL FILE

Tags: c++, idl, midl

Firstly,

Using **plain** C++, without ATL, MFC attempting to use COM Object interface.

Using **oleview** (OLE/COM Object viewer) - used to engineer the IDL code.

At this stage, using **MIDL** Compiler, now I'm having trouble trying to produce the following:

Syntax on cmd line:

midl /nologo /env win32 /tlb ".\S8_.tlb" /h ".\S8_.h" /iid ".\S8_i.c" S8.idl

- A corresponding .TLB (Type Library)
- A .H (header)
- An IID definitions include file (*_i.c)
- A proxy (*_p.c)

MIDL compiler error:

S8.IDL(513) : error MIDL2025 : syntax error : expecting a type specification near "S8SimObject"

```
    HRESULT LinkSimObjects(
                    [in] S8SimObject* SourceObject, ####line 513 ####
                    [in] S8SimObject* DestObject,
                    [in] float TravelTime);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## MIDL compiler error

S8.IDL(513) : **error MIDL2025** : syntax error : expecting a type specification near **"S8SimObject"**

### SOLVED

Add a **forward declaration** - at the TOP of IDL file:

- import "ocidl.idl";
- interface S8SimObject;

Answer (score 1):

Well, I do not really understand your question here, but following should help:

- Public enum definitions need to have their own *uuid* to be really public.
- I've seen that those enum definitions don't go into the type-library unless they are actually used in some interface method.  I do not know the reason for this, probably I missed something simple (like adding that enum to a library block, or whatever).
- `short` usually means a short integer, not a single-precision floating-point number.
- The equivalent of `float` is `single` in VB, but as I've seen on other questions of you, I suspect you actually meant replacing `single` with `float`.

By the way, I'd recommend to post one minimal (compilable) IDL file (stripped of most definitions), which resembles more or less what you're trying to compile.  This helps against some confusion, as you're for instance using `IS8Simulation` in your text, but `S8SimObject` in your copied IDL snippet.  And it would also help if you specify the expected result, and the unexpected (for you) error.

**Edit**

Well, this compile error you now inserted is simple: `S8SimObject` is not defined.  You need to always refer to the interface in the method declarations (`IS8Simulation`), never to the coclass which implements the interface.

As you said you're changing an existing IDL file here: What is the basic goal? If the original IDL file always uses `S8SimObject`, maybe the only problem is that the definition of `S8SimObject` is not included at the top of the IDL file?  If you've the type-library defining `S8SimObject` around, you can export the IDL of this interface by using OleView.