# IDL compile Error

Tags: visual-studio-2008, corba, idl, ace, tao

I want to compile an IDL file and when I compile the idl there is error that say "syntax error : expecting a type specification near "exception" " I read these links:[1](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2a8baa23-ee78-4cd2-ad15-d087f5aa836c/error-midl2025-syntax-error-?forum=vcgeneral),[2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mikewasson/2006/10/02/midl-error-annotation/) and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431206/no-type-definitions-in-pre-defined-idl-file) but they didn't help me my OS is windows 10 and my framework is MSVS2008 I tried my code in MSVS2006 and worked there if the problem is from my MIDL compiler how exactly I should fix it? which version of SDK should I install? I try some of them but didn't work.also I import "oaidl.idl" and "ocidl.idl" but didn't work.here is a part of my code:

```
//import "oaidl.idl";
//import "ocidl.idl";
module Quoter
{
  exception Invalid_Stock_Symbol {};

  interface Stock;

  interface Stock_Factory
  {

    Stock get_stock (in string stock_symbol)
      raises (Invalid_Stock_Symbol);
  };

  interface Stock
  {


    readonly attribute string symbol;

    readonly attribute string full_name;

    double price ();


  };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This is legal CORBA IDL but this has to be compiled using a CORBA IDL compiler like from [TAOX11](https://www.taox11.org), sounds that you are compiling it using MIDL which is not a CORBA IDL compiler. For TAO the IDL compiler is called tao_idl, maybe our free [CORBA Programmers Guide](https://www.remedy.nl/opensource/corbapg.html) will help.

Comment: In [this link](http://www.theaceorb.com/11a/releasenotes/bldgapps.html#68376) there a tutorial for compiling ACE/TAO with visual studio 2006 and like that I want to compile it in MSVS2008

Comment: It seems that you are well experienced in ACE/TAO.Is it possible I  have your Email for asking a few question about this subject.I really need help and I will be very grateful if you help me.@johnny

Comment: Check the ACE/TAO mailing lists as alternative support optio , direct support is only possible through the company I work for, see www.remedy.nl